# How to determine why cURL transfer is failing?

Tags: php, curl

I've been using cURL to get the output of an external page and it's worked great for months, but suddenly it stopped working. My code is like this:

```
$ch = curl_init($URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The URL is valid, I checked that it still works and it does, and through debugging I found that the `$output` variable's value is `false`, which according to the PHP manual is what `curl_exec()` returns on failure.

So, after working for a long time, and without any changes to my code (that I know of), the cURL transfer is suddenly not working.

How can I debug why it's not working?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would start with [curl_error()](http://php.net/curl_error)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [curl_error()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) function to see the error returned by curl.

Comment: @DavidHarris I've rolled back to the original but I thought the point of editing and having syntax options was to make sure everything was universal, easy to read and looked like any other post.